# What regulations are already in place regarding artificial general intelligences?

Tags: agi, legal

What regulations are already in place regarding artificial general intelligences? What reports or recommendations prepared by official government authorities were already published?

So far, I know of [Sir David King's report done for UK government](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/2/5ae9b434-8f8e-11db-9ba3-0000779e2340.html).

Comment: [law.se] might be a good place for this question, too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that it has yielded any actual reports or regulations yet, but in the USA, the White House has been running a series of interagency workshops / working groups dedicated to [Preparing for the Future of Artificial Intelligence](https://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2016/05/03/preparing-future-artificial-intelligence).

Some of those sessions have been dedicated to legal / governance issues.